# ./write_eeprom.sh: line 29: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: bash, python-2.x, ubuntu-20.04

Error: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

qr_heisys=$1

testpath='/home/home/Heisys/tester/app/dut/variant'

if [[ $testdesc == "-h" ]]

then
        echo "script to write data to Board EEPROM of Heisys"

        echo "eeprom is at address 0x55"

        echo "first argument is testdesc"

        echo "second argument is qr"

        echo "usage: write_eeprom.sh "write to eeprom"  ""$qr_heisys"""

        exit 0
fi

# teststep "${testdesc}"   TSN: not needed

echo "qr_heisys = ""$qr_heisys"

echo "${testpath}${qr2eeprom}qr2eeprom.py "$qr_heisys"""



if [[? -ne "0"]]

then

        return $EXIT_FAIL "Error writing QR Code to eeprom"

else

        return $EXIT_PASS "Write QR to Boardeeprom was successfully PASS"

fi
```

I try to execute the code using ./write_eeprom.sh command on the terminal.

When googled the issue, i was mentioned about parsing error or double quote. I tried , but I am still not getting what is the issue.
Please can someone advice.
I used shellcheck.net too

Comment: What is "the code"? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: So when I googled this error, I tried to check or edit the double quote. But still it didn't work. Then I later checked on shellcheck.net, it said parsing error, but still I didn't understand.

Comment: So, the code bascially is that, Im trying to migrate one .py(qr2eeprom.py) script into the .sh script(write_eeprom.sh).

Comment: Hence, I am not understanding what should I do or the solution for this.

Comment: The line `echo "${testpath}${qr2eeprom}qr2eeprom.py "$qr_heisys"""` has an odd number of quotes.  There are also a number of places where you appear to be using syntax from some non-shell language. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point out some of the problems.

Comment: How do I up-vote your comment ?  As it helped me @GordonDavisson